# Can a taxonomy of a custom post type be called 'category'?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

It seems not possible to write :

```
register_taxonomy('category',array('events'), array(
        'hierarchical'                  => true,
        'labels'                        => $labels_category_events,
        'show_ui'                       => true,
        'show_in_rest'                  => true,
        'show_admin_column'             => true,
        'query_var'                     => true,
        'rewrite'                       => array( 'slug' => "evenements/category" ),
        'has_archive'                   => true,
    ));
```

without having conflict with "real" categories ?
Thank to confirm ... or not .

Comment: No, you can't name it exactly the same slug. However, you could call them categories in the labels but register `even_category` or something similar as the slug so they don't conflict.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#reserved-terms

Answer (score 1):

As said, you can't and here's the list of reserved terms: https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Answer (score 0):

No, as WordPress by default register a taxonomy called category (which is linked with blog posts).  However, you can assign this taxonomy(category) to your custom post type too.
using the following code snippet.

```
add_action( 'init', 'pixel_add_category_cpt' );
function pixel_add_category_cpt() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'events', 'course' );

}
```